# Can I emplace a value into a vector that is stored in a map in C++?

Tags: c++, emplace

I was wondering if it's possible to emplace a value into a vector that is stored in a map.

Currently I do this like so...

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> my_collection;
my_collection["Key"].push_back("MyValue");
```

I was thinking I could do the following and C++ would be smart enough to realize it should add it to the vector... but I get a memory compile error.

```
my_collection.emplace("Key", "MyValue");
```

Comment: Your first snippet is the only way to do that. There is no magic that would let compiler deduce what you are thinking, it can only work with what you code - what should it do with second snippet? Replace all vector content with this value? Insert it (at what position)? Or assume that you made a mistake, because types doesn't match?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a vector, emplace into it, and then move the vector. This way your object will neither be copied or moved:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> my_collection;
std::vector<std::string> temp;
temp.emplace_back("MyValue");
my_collection["Key"] = std::move(temp);
```

Alternatively, you create the vector in the map and work on a reference:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> my_collection;
auto &keyVec = my_collection["Key"];
keyVec.emplace_back("MyValue");
```

Conveniently, this boils down to:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> my_collection;
my_collection["Key"].emplace_back("MyValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter how *smart* C++ gets, it still has to respect the language rules and the public interfaces. `std::map` does have an [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) member. You need to use that.

The problem is that there is no way to construct a vector by moving elements into it (because of how `std::initializer_list` is designed - don't get me started)

If you don't care about that and you can accept copying elements into the vector then all you need to do is:

```
auto test()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> my_collection;

    my_collection.emplace("key"s, std::vector{"MyValue"s});
}
```

The above will copy `"MyValue"s` into a vector then will move the key and the vector into the map.

However if you do want moves or if you have move-only types then there is some extra work.

So I create a little utility function which does that: creates a vector by moving rvalues passed to it:

```
template <class... Args>
auto make_vector(Args&&... args)
{
    using T = std::remove_reference_t<std::common_type_t<Args...>>;
    static_assert((... && std::is_same_v<T, std::remove_reference_t<Args>>));

    auto v = std::vector<T>{};
    v.reserve(sizeof...(Args));
    (..., v.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args))); 

    return v;
}

auto test()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> my_collection;

    my_collection.emplace("key", make_vector("MyValue"s));
}
```

Comment: But this way "MyValue" will not be emplaced.

Comment: @ypnos how do you figure?

Comment: I might be wrong but I would assume for this the object needs to be copy-constructible, even if it could be elided, no?

Comment: @ypnos ok, time for some research.

Comment: From my reading of the standard, constructing a `std::vector` from an initializer list works as if by calling the constructor taking iterators. The constructor taking iterators emplaces each element from `*i`, where `i` is the iterator. The iterator type of `std::initializer_list<T>` is `T const*`. Thus the element of the `std::vector` here is being constructed out of a `std::string const&`, which copies.

Comment: @HTNW god damn initializer list. Yes, it will be copied.